# updating the variable for a different function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble updating the marker for the Maps component using the Local_Value. getMap() function is supposed to update the value of Local_Value but it does not update the value Globally to update the marker.

The getMap() function imports one of two options if a option selector (PO, CA) and based on that option selected, it will update the local_Value.

The Maps component is a react-google-maps component that points to one location on the map, and when the Local_Value is updated, the location is also changed. (this is the part that is not working properly).

```
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Pointer from "./Pointer";

var Local_Value = "CA"; //This is the value i want to change

export function getMap(props) { //I try to change the value here
  if (props === "PO") {
    Local_Value = "PO";
  }
  if (props === "CA") {
    Local_Value = "CA";
  }
}

const Maps = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQcpd9cczzgwtbptuv2gptBcInO44zG0o&v=6.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `700px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
)((props) => {

  if (Local_Value === "PO") { //try updated value to change location
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={props.locationData.zoom}
        defaultCenter={props.locationData.latlong}
      >
        {props.language.P_LOCATION_DATA.map((data, index) => (
          <Pointer {...props} key={index} data={data} />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
  if (Local_Value === "CA") {
    console.log(Local_Value);
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={props.locationData.zoom}
        defaultCenter={props.locationData.latlong}
      >
        {props.language.C_LOCATION_DATA.map((data, index) => (
          <Pointer {...props} key={index} data={data} />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
});

Maps.propTypes = { locationData: PropTypes.object.isRequired };
export default Maps;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question, the problem is that React Functional components do NOT naturally re-run the variable construction phase.

This means that even though your Local_Value is changing your "const Maps = compose(...)" will never be ran again

React has a solution for this is is called useReducer

---

The description is quite long, but the React Team has done a great job documenting how to fix it. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html